# ReactJS - Print specific elements in the DOM

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, printing, media-queries

I am using [ReactJS](https://reactjs.org) on an App and currently **need to be able to print some elements from the page on user's request** (click on a button).

I chose to use the [CSS media-query type print](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media#media_types) (`@media print`) to be able to check if an element should be printed, based on a selector that could be from a class or attribute on an Element. The strategy would be to hide everything but those "printable" elements with a stylesheet looking like:

```css
@media print {
    *:not([data-print]) {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

However, for this to work I need to also add the chosen print selector (here the attribute `data-print`) on every parent element each printable element has.

To do that here's what I've tried so far:

```
export default function PrintButton() {
    useEffect(() => {
        const handleBeforePrint = () => {
            printNodeSelectors.forEach((selector) => {
                const printableElement = document.querySelector(selector);
                if (printableElement != null) {
                    let element = printableElement;
                    while (element.parentElement) {
                        element.setAttribute("data-print", "");
                        element = element.parentElement;
                    }
                    element.setAttribute("data-print", "");
                }
            });
        };
        const handleAfterPrint = () => {
            printNodeSelectors.forEach((selector) => {
                const printableElement = document.querySelector(selector);
                if (printableElement != null) {
                    let element = printableElement;
                    while (element.parentElement) {
                        element.removeAttribute("data-print");
                        element = element.parentElement;
                    }
                    element.removeAttribute("data-print");
                }
            });
        };
        window.addEventListener("beforeprint", handleBeforePrint);
        window.addEventListener("afterprint", handleAfterPrint);
        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener("beforeprint", handleBeforePrint);
            window.removeEventListener("afterprint", handleAfterPrint);
        };
    }, []);

    return <button onClick={() => window.print()}>Print</button>;
}
```

With `printNodeSelectors` being a const Array of string selectors.

Unfortunately it seems that React ditch out all my dirty DOM modification right after I do them

I'd like to find a way to achieve this without having to manually put everywhere in the app who should be printable, while working on a React App, would someone knows how to do that?

Comment: I don'( understand how this could work because the body element will have display: none from the CSS you have given - what am I missing? Would visibility: hidden/visible be better choices (you can set a child of a parent that has visibility hidden to itself be visible).

Comment: Thanks, indeed the `<html>` element would have been avoided, my mistake I'll update the post to reflect that. However React is still removing those modifications as soon as they are made and visibility would unfortunately still leave elements in the flow showing white blank spaces instead of only showing elements that I want

Answer (score 0):

Just CSS should be enough to hide all Elements which do not have the `data-print` attribute AND which do not have such Element *in their descendants*.

Use the [`:has`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) CSS pseudo-class (in combination with `:not` one) to express that 2nd condition (selector on descendants):

```css
@media print {
  *:not([data-print]):not(:has([data-print])) {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Caution: ancestors of Elements with `data-print` attribute would not match, hence their text nodes (not wrapped by a tag) would not be hidden when printing:

```html
<div>
  <span>should not print</span>
  <span data-print>but this should</span>
  Caution: text node without tag may be printed...
</div>
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/6x34ad50/1/ (you can launch the print preview browser feature to see the effect, or rely on the coloring)

Similar but just coloring to directly see the effect:

```css
*:not([data-print]):not(:has([data-print])) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>should not print (be colored in red)</span>
  <span data-print>but this should</span>
  Caution: text node without tag may be printed...
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! However this doesn't take into account that I'm using a React App that is overriding the change of attributes made through DOM manipulation. Also the :has selector isn't largely supported yet https://caniuse.com/css-has

Answer (score 0):

After some thoughts, tries and errors it appears that even though I managed to put the attribute selector on the parents I completely missed the children of the elements I wanted to print! (React wasn't at all removing the attributes from a mysterious render cycle in the end)

Here's a now functioning Component:

```
export default function PrintButton() {
    
    useEffect(() => {
        const handleBeforePrint = () => {
            printNodeSelectors.forEach((selector) => {
                const printableElement = document.querySelector(selector);
                if (printableElement != null) {
                    const elements: Element[] = [];
                    // we need to give all parents and children a data-print attribute for them to be displayed on print
                    const addParents = (element: Element) => {
                        if (element.parentElement) {
                            elements.push(element.parentElement);
                            addParents(element.parentElement);
                        }
                    };
                    addParents(printableElement);
                    const addChildrens = (element: Element) => {
                        elements.push(element);
                        Array.from(element.children).forEach(addChildrens);
                    };
                    addChildrens(printableElement);
                    elements.forEach((element) => element.setAttribute("data-print", ""));
                }
            });
        };
        const handleAfterPrint = () => {
            document.querySelectorAll("[data-print]").forEach((element) => element.removeAttribute("data-print"));
        };
        window.addEventListener("beforeprint", handleBeforePrint);
        window.addEventListener("afterprint", handleAfterPrint);
        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener("beforeprint", handleBeforePrint);
            window.removeEventListener("afterprint", handleAfterPrint);
        };
    }, []);

    return <button onClick={() => window.print()}>Print</button>;
}
```

I usually don't like messing with the DOM while using React but here it allows me to keep everything in the component without having to modify anything else around (though I'd agree that those printNodeSelectors need to be chosen from outside and aren't dynamic at the moment)